# ¿Comó cambiar tarea CRON sin detener la ejecución del servicio?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, schedule

Buen día comunidad.

Estoy generando un servicio, el cual debera ejecutar un proceso cada cierto tiempo, actualmente lo realizo metodos CRON, el valor de tiempo lo guardo en una Base de Datos Oracle y recupero ese valor para luego usuarlo.
Sin embargo, lo que ahora requiero es que si este valor llegara a cambiar, el servicio lo tome y haga su ejecución de acuerdo al valor de la BD.
Anexo codigo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer, DisposableBean {
@Autowired
    private ConexionBDDao conexionBDDao;

    @Autowired
    private ConsumeService consumeService;

    private Map<String, Object> cronExpressions;

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {

        cronExpressions = conexionBDDao.getKey("PG"); // para almacenar la expresión cron en la base de datos para que podamos cambiar sobre la marcha cuando el servidor se está ejecutando.

        Stream.of(StringUtils.split(cronExpressions.get("return").toString(), "|")).forEach(cron -> {
            Runnable runnable = () -> consumeService.service();

            // Runnable runnable = () -> consumeService.service();

            Trigger trigger = new Trigger() {
                @Override
                public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                    Map<String, Object> newCronExpressions = conexionBDDao.getKey("PG");
                    if (!StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(newCronExpressions.get("return").toString(),
                            cronExpressions.get("return").toString())) {
                        taskRegistrar.setTriggerTasksList(new ArrayList<>());
                        configureTasks(taskRegistrar); // llamando recursivamente.
                        taskRegistrar.destroy(); // destruye las tareas previamente programadas.
                        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(executor); 
                        taskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(); // esto programará la tarea con nuevos cambios de cron.
                        return null; // devuelve nulo cuando el cron cambió para que el disparador se detenga.
                    }
                    CronTrigger crontrigger = new CronTrigger(cron);
                    return crontrigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
                }
            };
            taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(runnable, trigger);
        });
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

He tomado la siguiente referencia: [DZone: multiple cron task with spring boot scheduler](https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-cron-task-with-spring-boot-scheduler)

Actualmente toma el valor de tiempo que esta en la BD y una vez que llega a este tiempo el proceso se ejecuta, pero si cambiamos el valor de la BD, el servicio no detecta el cambio y ya no realiza nada. 
Alguna sugerencia o que estoy realizando mal, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

puedes añadir el dato en el properties por ejemplo:

```
fixed-delay-scheduledService.in.milliseconds=5000
```

Esto serían 5 segundos.
Y recoges ese dato así:

```
@Value("${fixed-delay-scheduledService.in.milliseconds}")
private String value;
```

De esta forma tienes el valor como variable de entorno y si usas Docker puedes cambiarle el valor, reiniciar el contenedor y ya está. De hecho Docker tiene un parámetro para reiniciar automáticamente el contenedor si detecta alguna modificación en el archivo que contiene las variables de entorno.

Otra opción es coger el valor directamente dentro de la anotación @Scheduled como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
@Service
public class OrderPriorityUseCase implements IOrderPriorityUseCase {

@Autowired IOrderProcessorService iOrderProcessorService;

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed-delay-processPriorityOrder.in.milliseconds}")
public void processPriorityOrder(){

    iOrderProcessorService.orderScheduler();

}

}
```